# MongoError: $graphLookup reached maximum memory consumption

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Mongo `graphLookup` query to fetch a result from the collection.

I am sending a query with depth `10`, but I am getting the following error :

> `$graphLookup` reached maximum memory consumption

Not able to understand what is this error? why this error is coming what is the reason behind this? and what is the solution for this?

Comment: As a workaround, could you query with a smaller depth, and then query again from the end of the previous query?

Comment: my data size is high so how i can do this?

Comment: If you use `"depthField"`, you can get the deepest result from the first limited (with `"maxDepth"`) query, and then use that as the start for the next query.

Answer (score 1):

`$graphLookup` stage has a 100MB memory limit. So, when it exceeds that you will get the error "*$graphLookup reached maximum memory*".

You can refer to the `$graphLookup` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#memory) for this.

There is also a [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38560) awaiting for the consideration by the MongoDB query team, to add `$project` in `$graphLookup`. Once that happens, any field which has huge data can be excluded which in return will help to bring the utilisation within the 100MB limit cap.

Comment: 100 MB memory limit meaning it is result limit or process limit?

Comment: Memory limit is for the $graphLookup stage alone. There could be multiple stages in your pipeline, but the $graphLookup stage should not consume more than 100MB.

Comment: is any way to increase that limit? and how to debug which stag is faling

Comment: currently there is no way to increase the limit.
You can comment out all other pipeline stages, and just keep the $graphLookup one to check. You can also reduce the maxdepth to 4-5 and see if it it helps.

Comment: but when I add one condition in restrictSearchWithMatch. the above error will not come not able to understand why?

Comment: is any alternative present for $graphLookup?

Comment: @SurajDalvi If you include a "restrictSearchWithMatch" condition the memory used by the stage will be less since there is lesser data to be kept in memory. 
There are multiple Jira tickets, you can vote on this one for example: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38560

Comment: I was learning Mongo and considering a migration before I've hit this scenario. I work in the insurance industry, where downline is the core of the business. I tried to bring just a couple of levels down for an agent today (3,700 agents) and all I needed was their IDs, but $graphlookup is bringing the entire document for each downline. This agent has 20 levels deep. I guess I will stick to SQL Server until this get fixed.